# How to handle this below window/pop up in chrome when i click on print link . I need to recognize it and click cancel on it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome

When I click on Print link in chrome browser , a pop is opened which shows it as a PDF file and then on the right side there are printing options with save , print etc buttons . Now when I click the print button which is on Browser , this pop up opens and the execution just pauses and I am stuck .

Comment: also looking for solution. any update?

Answer (score 1):

This would help you. I have tried a sample run with [W3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print) print example.

```java
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","driverpath");
            driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print");
            driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
            //js executor to prevent print function
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.print=function(){};");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@onclick=\"window.print()\"]")).click();
```

This will not make the print action so that print dialog box will not be popped up.

Comment: hi , Thanks for the answer . i tried the above like  this below but executions pauses after click .        detailsPage.getAlertDetailsPrint1().click();
  getDriver().switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
  // js executor to prevent print function
  ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("window.print=function(){};");
  getDriver().findElementByXPath(("//button[@onclick=\"window.print()\"]")).click();

Comment: i need to click print button on applictaion page , which makes this pop up appear and i need to verify it this pop up appears and then click cancel